# Como é o algorítimo de uma aplicação P2P?

Tags: algoritmo, conexão

Existem vários programas P2P, sei que o conceito é que cada computador é como um cliente e servidor ao mesmo tempo, e que eles comunicam entre si. Sobre esse tipo de comunicação:

- Se não tem um servidor, como o programa sabe onde estão os seus "irmãos"?
- Como seria o algorítimo de um programa P2P para transmissão de mensagens?
- É possível criar uma comunicação P2P em uma rede local?
- Existe uma porta padrão para esse tipo de conexão ou posso escolher qualquer uma "disponível"?

Comment: @FelipeDoiradinho, fiz uma atualização na pergunta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Existem várias implementações de protocolos *peer to peer* (*entre iguais* em tradução livre). De maneira geral, eles se caracterizam por:

- **Comunicação de conteúdo não-linear**: Grandes conteúdos podem ser quebrados em pacotes menores, e enviados fora de ordem (o cliente se encarrega de organizar os pacotes);
- **Auto-resolução de serviços**: O cliente sabe, por si só, como procurar e iniciar a comunicação com outros elementos iguais a ele mesmo presentes na mesma malha lógica;
- **Não-confiança**: O cliente não assume nenhum aspecto externo como imutável e confiável (pacotes podem ser corrompidos, *peers* podem se desconectar, ou mandar pacotes errados);
- **Roteamento de controle**: O cliente sabe como passar adiante requisições que ele não pode cumprir.

Alguns serviços implementam ainda o conceito de rastreadores (*trackers*) que são serviços onde certas informações (como tabelas de roteamento e correlações entre peers e conteúdo) são compiladas e podem ser checadas para maior velocidade de resolução.

Note que *trackers* funcionam apenas como uma dica; o cliente, de posse da lista de *peers* de um certo conteúdo, tenta se conectar a eles e validar a informação que eles realmentem o possuem. *Trackers* com muitas informações erradas podem entrar para uma *blacklist*, por exemplo.

Vamos assumir o gráfico abaixo como uma descrição prática de uma malha peer-to-peer, e simular alguns casos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Resolução de *peers*: A máquina **7** envia um mensagem em estilo *broadcast* para a rede, sem nenhum alvo específico, perguntando por membros da mesma malha. As máquinas **5** e **6** respondem, e são adicionadas à lista de peers que **7** pode enxergar.
- Resolução de conteúdo: **7** pergunta tanto à **6** quanto a **5** onde o conteúdo **A** pode ser encontrado. **6** responde que o conteúdo existe em **2** e **1**, enquanto que 5 responde que **2** possui o conteúdo. A máquina 7 então tenta estabeler diretamente uma conexão com **2** e **1**, e as marca como prováveis repositórios de **A**.
- Transmissão de conteúdo: **7** pergunta a **2** a quantidade de pacotes que compõem **A**. A resposta, 5 pacotes, vem junto com a indicação que **2** possui apenas os pacotes **AP1** e **AP2**. **7** então solicita o pacote **AP1** a **2**, enquanto pergunta a **1** quais pacotes de **A** ele tem; **7** tentará então coordenar a solicitação de pacotes de maneira a cobrir todo o conteúdo (AP1-AP5).
- Anúncios: **4**, que também possui o conteúdo **A**, entra na malha, anunciando sua presença a **5**. **5**, por sua vez, avisa a **7** que outro cliente contendo **A** está disponível.

Note que em nenhum momento qualquer uma das máquinas trata seus *peers* como um servidor clássico. Este tipo de estrutura pode ser implementada em rede local, e se beneficiar da (geralmente) maior confiabilidade, velocidade e estabilidade do ambiente.

Comment: Quando você diz "envia uma mensagem em estilo _broadcast_ para a rede", como exatamente isso é feito? Não preciso de nenhum "alvo" pra enviar uma requisição/mensagem? Tem algum exemplo em C#, PHP ou outra linguagem similar?

Comment: @KaduAmaral Existem várias maneiras, e algumas não exigem um 'alvo' para suas mensagens - apenas que eles estejam na mesma subrede. Você pode utilizar o protocolo UDP em estilo broadcast ou multicast, por exemplo. Você pode ver um exemplo de implementação em C# neste link: http://feodrippe.com/post/9867540504/udp-codigos-em-c-para-cliente-e-servidor

Comment: haha interessante, é que trabalho com desenvolvimento web, ou seja protocolo HTTP na veia, nem lembrava que existia UDP e TPC, hahah

Comment: @KaduAmaral e você pode usar os dois em conjunto, quando necessário. =)

Answer (score 5):

Não existe um servidor, mas existe um "enfileirador", se chama **Tracker**.

**O que são Trackers?**

Os trackers são servidores responsáveis em dizer ao seu programa de P2P o IP dos seeders e leechers. Quanto mais trackers, mais seeders e leechers.

Portanto, o seu cliente P2P envia ao tracker (provavelmente webservice) as informações da sua conexão (IP, PORTA, etc). Outro usuário com o mesmo cliente, buscando uma pequena parte do arquivo, recebe esta informação do(s) tracker(s) e portanto, faz o download. Quanto mais trackers, repetindo, mais partes disponíveis pois estes por sua vez multiplicam as informações de clientes (e portanto, as partes).

O algorítimo deve apenas seguir este workflow e é claro, não existe apenas um algorítimo, uma vez que os trackers também usam programas próprios seguindo o padrão P2P.

Comment: Para que eu possa fazer um sistema p2p em uma rede local, terei também que criar o tracker?

Comment: Bem, **KaduAmaral**, se a intenção é criar um sistema P2P em uma rede local, eu acho que o conceito FTP seja mais adequado. De qualquer forma: sim, basta setar uma máquina a função de delegar e receber informações dos clientes (que também são servidores kkkk)

Comment: kkk, mas o foco principal é a troca de mensagens, sem um servidor intermediando essa troca, tendo o tracker (servidor) apenas pra informar onde está a outra "ponta da corda" não tem problema.

Comment: Ah tá hehe Qual seria a plataforma (OS e linguagem)? Já adiantando, o pattern **Observer** pode ajudar, veja aqui (há exemplos de implementação no final da página): https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer

Comment: Sistemas windows provavelmente em C#, talvez futuramente em python, ambos para estudo das linguagens.

Comment: Ah sim! Adoro C#! Dá uma olhada: http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server.htm  e  http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server-programming.htm