# Envio de mensagem para um rede local no estilo broadcast via UDP

Tags: c#, algoritmo

Fiz uma [pergunta sobre conexão P2P](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71004/como-%C3%A9-o-algor%C3%ADtimo-de-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-p2p), então com uma das repostas surgiu a dúvida: Como enviar uma mensagem em uma rede local via UDP no estilo *broadcast*, sem um destinatário específico?

Com isso gostaria das seguintes soluções:

- Como buscar um possíveis destinatário utilizando UDP no estilo *Broadcast*?
- Como enviar mensagens via UDP?
- **Qual a lógica por trás do "estilo" *Broadcast* e como ele é feito utilizando protocolo UDP.**

Se possível com um exemplo em C#.

Comment: **Kadu**, são perfeitos para você: - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/607801/SimpleplusChatplusprogramplusinplusC - http://sourceforge.net/projects/basic-chat-program/ - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97ec13/how-to-make-a-chat-application-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Felipe, obrigado pela resposta, vou olhar os códigos, mas ainda falta uma parte importante da pergunta que é "_Gostaria de saber a lógica por trás dessa requisição_", ou seja, eu gostaria de saber um pouco sobre a parte teórica de uma protocolo UDP, que na verdade esqueci de adicionar na pergunta...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma das maneiras de entender como UDP funciona é comparando-o ao TCP.

**TCP**

- **Conexão**: Para utilizar o protocolo TCP você precisa estabelecer uma conexão com um (e apenas um) *host* remoto.
- **Comunicação bidirecional**: Uma vez estabelecida a conexão, os dois pontos podem enviar mensagens (razão pela qual o tunelamento IP funciona)
- **Ponto-a-ponto**: Uma conexão envolve unica e exclusivamente dois pontos.
- **Transmissão garantida**: Uma vez que um pacote tenha sido enviado para um host remoto, o protocolo monitora a entrega (ou avisa a respeito de falhas).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**UDP**

- **Sem conexão**: Você não estabelece conexões quando emitindo pacotes UDP; apenas especifica um alvo.
- **Sem garantias**: O protocolo não implementa nenhum tipo de garantia que o pacote chegará ao host de destino.
- **Utilização de máscaras**: Um pacote pode ser enviado para múltiplos hosts ao mesmo tempo quando o alvo é uma máscara.

No exemplo abaixo, um pacote UDP enviado para o endereço `192.168.1.255` a partir do host 192.168.1.15 será recebido por **todos** os hosts da subrede, *inclusive* 192.168.1.15; O octeto `.255` equivale, em termos gerais e no exemplo dado, a 'todos os hosts sob 192.168.1'.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo de emissão de pacote UDP (em C#):

```
static void SendUdp(int srcPort, string dstIp, int dstPort, byte[] data)
{
    using (UdpClient c = new UdpClient(srcPort))
        c.Send(data, data.Length, dstIp, dstPort);
}

SendUdp(11000, "192.168.1.255", 11000, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Olá, eu sou o Goku!"));
```

O exemplo acima envia para todos os hosts da subrede atual e porta 11000 um pacote UDP.

Comment: Ono, essa máscara é a mesma que tem no configurador de redes do Windows? Lá quando eu coloco um IP fixo de rede, ele preenche automaticamente o campo "_Mascara de Sub Rede IPv4_", então para enviar um pacote para uma rede eu envio para essa máscara?

Comment: @KaduAmaral A interpretação do valor é 'quase' o mesmo, no sentido de permitir segmentação. Porém sub-rede é um conceito completamente diferente. Vale a pena dar uma olhada na definição: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1scara_de_rede