# Um chatbot local pode ser considerado um sistema P2P?

Tags: python, redes, sistemas-distribuídos, chatterbot

A princípio tinha feito um *chatbot* que se conectava ao Telegram, mas como a mensagem passa por um servidor acredito eu que não se caracterize como um sistema p2p (cliente, cliente).

Em seguida, fiz um *chatbot* simples que, a partir de um treinamento, responde minhas mensagens através do terminal. Não entendo muito de redes então não sei se essa comunicação se caracteriza como (cliente, cliente) comunicando entre si.

Segue o código do *chatbot* local:

```
# -*- codding: utf-8 -*-
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
import os

chatbot = ChatBot("Futaba")

trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)

for arquivos in os.listdir('arquivos'):
    chats = open('arquivos/' + arquivos, 'r').readlines()
    trainer.train(chats)

print("Hey, meu nome é Futaba")
response = chatbot.get_response("Hey!")
print(response)

while True:
    resq = input('Você: ')
    resp = chatbot.get_response(resq)
    if float(response.confidence) > 0.9:
        print('Futaba: ' + str(resp))
    else:
        print('Como você tem se sentido?')
```

Se caracteriza como um sistema par a par? Se não, é possível modificar este para que ele se torne ou é preferível fazer outro usando um *framework* como o Pyro?

Comment: Por que precisa fazer esse tipo de classificação? É algum trabalho de faculdade?

Comment: Isto explica o p2p https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71039/3635 ? Não entendo do assunto para falar.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Para ser *peer to peer* precisa ser capaz de um chat se conectar com outro sem intermediários.

Pior ainda, um *chatbot* deve operar em um chat existente e não ser um chat, se ele for um chat, antes de ser um *chatbot* você tem um chat. Um *chatbot* poderia em tese até funcionar em algo que não tem conexão alguma.

Então a pergunta toda não faz sentido, incluindo a parte final, ela procura relação em coisas que não existem, rede e bot são coisas que podem ter uma relação fraca em determinado momento mas são coisas diferentes. Não sei nem porque isso é importante.

Se fosse um chat teria algum sentido e aí se questionaria se ele depende de um servidor para funcionar ou não, ou se depende só para estabelecer uma conexão inicial ou se toda conversa passa por ele. A questão do Telegram tem a ver com ser P2P ou não, o *chatbot* nada tem a ver com isso.

Isto ainda não seria um sistema distribuído, a distribuição só ocorre se o processamento principal é distribuído.